Quarkus Redis Client is creating huge amount of connections
In my quarkus redis client, I am creating way more connections than my connection pool should allow. I am not sure why this is happening. My connection pool has maxPoolSize = 6 maxPoolWaiting = 24 but yet my elasticache service shows that my current connections on my shards went up to 1.4k and 700. 
Why is this happening and how can I limit the amount of connections that my quarkus client is creating? This amount of connections is causing me the cache to have a  high cpu usage which is not good for scaling.
I am using    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
This is the code I've been using to customize the RedisOptions.
    @Override
    public void customize(String clientName, RedisOptions options) {
        NetClientOptions netOptions = options.getNetClientOptions();
        netOptions.setSsl(true).setHostnameVerificationAlgorithm("HTTPS")
                .setReconnectAttempts(reconnectAttempts).setReconnectInterval(reconnectInterval).setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setTcpKeepAlive(true).setIdleTimeout(5000).setIdleTimeoutUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

and this is how I am using the RedisClient in my code

    @Inject
    public CacheService(
            @RedisClientName("cache") @NotNull ReactiveRedisDataSource reactiveRedisDataSource,
    ) {
        commands = reactiveRedisDataSource.value(byte[].class);
        keyCommands = reactiveRedisDataSource.key();
}

    public Uni<Optional<Item>> getItem(String key) {
        return commands.get(key).onItem().transform("turnFromBytestoItem");
    }

and this is my connection logic in the application.properties
quarkus.redis.cache.hosts=rediss://${HOST:localhost}:6379
quarkus.redis.cache.client-type=cluster
quarkus.redis.cache.replicas=share


I was able to greatly help this issue by upgrading from  <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version> to quarkus version 3.2. My connections went down from a max of 6k in prod to a max of 300 in prod. Also, the engine CPU went down from 3% to 0.5%. However, by upgrading I did start getting more cache misses which is what I am solving now.
